# thread 1: exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_1386_invop,subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift

please help me solve this error!

[http://i.imgur.com/cMfkMRH.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg084.png)

I don't know why "let noodle = noodles[indexPath.row]" is erro

but "let recipe = recipes[indexPath.row]" is OK!

above codes are in the function

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {"
}

```
var recipes:[Recipe] = [
    Recipe(name: "巧克力手工餅乾", type: "餅乾", material: "1.無鹽奶油  150g\n2.低筋麵粉  275g\n3.可可粉  25g\n4.蛋  1顆\n5.細砂糖  100g\n6.泡打粉(可省)  1/2小匙", image: "ChocolateCookie.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"", userPhoto:"小璧.jpg", userName:"小璧" ),
    //Recipes(name: "巧克力手工餅乾", type: "餅乾", material: "1.無鹽奶油\n2.低筋麵粉\n3.可可粉\n4.蛋\n5.細砂糖\n6.泡打粉(可省)", image: "ChocolateCookie.jpg", isVisited: false, amount:"150g\n275g\n25g\n1顆\n100g\n1/2小匙"),
    Recipe(name: "辣味雞肉義大利麵", type: "麵食", material: "1.義大利麵\n2.雞胸肉\n3.洋蔥\n4.白酒\n5.蘆筍\n6.鴻喜菇\n7.玉米筍\n8.甜椒\n9.鮮奶油\n10.奶油\n11.蒜碎\n12.花椒油\n13.義大利香料", image: "pasta.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"180g\n50g\n15g\n50g\n15g\n10g\n10g\n5g\n150g\n10g\n5g\n20g\n2g", userPhoto:"Adrian Hsiao.jpg", userName:"Adrian Hsiao" ),
    Recipe(name: "巧克力戚風蛋糕(6吋）", type: "甜點", material: "1.低筋麵粉\n2.無糖可可粉\n3.植物油\n4.牛奶\n5.蛋黃\n6.蛋白\n7.細砂糖\n8.蛋糕裝飾(奶油）", image: "chocolateCake.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"45g\n15g\n30g\n60g\n3個\n3個\n45g\n適量", userPhoto:"維尼Winnie.jpg", userName:"維尼Winnie" ),
    Recipe(name: "蜂蜜法式吐司磚", type: "早餐", material: "1.吐司\n2.蛋\n3.牛奶\n4.蜂蜜\n5.糖粉", image: "toaste.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"2片\n1顆\n20CC\n依喜好\n依喜好", userPhoto:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可.jpg", userName:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可" ),
    Recipe(name: "焗烤海鮮筆管麵", type: "麵食", material: "1.筆管麵\n 2.洋蔥\n3.蛤蜊\n4.透抽\n5.鮮蝦\n6.蒜頭\n7.水\n8.康寶濃湯粉\n9.鹽\n10.起司絲\n11.煮熟綠花椰菜", image: "pasta2.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"1/3包\n1顆\n適量\n適量\n適量\n三小瓣\n1杯半\n半包\n少許\n適量\n適量", userPhoto:"阿渝師～美味廚房.jpg", userName:"阿渝師～美味廚房" ),
    Recipe(name: "秀珍菇麻油雞", type: "冬令進補", material: "1.秀珍菇\n2.帶骨雞腿\n3.米酒\n4.麻油\n5.薑", image: "large_3649cc5a24aef9ec.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"450g\n2隻\n600c.c\n6大匙\n1大塊", userPhoto:"小舖の廚房.jpg", userName:"小舖の廚房" ),
    Recipe(name: "清熱除痘湯", type: "夏日清爽", material: "1.花旗參\n2.蒟蒻\n3.豬肉\n4.紅棗\n5.薑\n6.鹽\n7.水", image: "soap.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"23克\n38克\n150克\n4粒\n1片\n1茶匙\n10杯", userPhoto:"唐安麒超猛瘦身食譜.jpg", userName:"唐安麒超猛瘦身食譜" ),
    Recipe(name: "蜂蜜法式吐司磚", type: "早餐", material: "1.吐司\n2.蛋\n3.牛奶\n4.蜂蜜\n5.糖粉", image: "toaste.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"2片\n1顆\n20CC\n依喜好\n依喜好", userPhoto:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可.jpg", userName:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可" ),
    Recipe(name: "蜂蜜法式吐司磚", type: "早餐", material: "1.吐司\n2.蛋\n3.牛奶\n4.蜂蜜\n5.糖粉", image: "toaste.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"2片\n1顆\n20CC\n依喜好\n依喜好", userPhoto:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可.jpg", userName:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可" ),
   Recipe(name: "蜂蜜法式吐司磚", type: "早餐", material: "1.吐司\n2.蛋\n3.牛奶\n4.蜂蜜\n5.糖粉", image: "toaste.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"2片\n1顆\n20CC\n依喜好\n依喜好", userPhoto:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可.jpg", userName:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可" ),
    Recipe(name: "蜂蜜法式吐司磚", type: "早餐", material: "1.吐司\n2.蛋\n3.牛奶\n4.蜂蜜\n5.糖粉", image: "toaste.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"2片\n1顆\n20CC\n依喜好\n依喜好", userPhoto:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可.jpg", userName:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可" ),
    Recipe(name: "蜂蜜法式吐司磚", type: "早餐", material: "1.吐司\n2.蛋\n3.牛奶\n4.蜂蜜\n5.糖粉", image: "toaste.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"2片\n1顆\n20CC\n依喜好\n依喜好", userPhoto:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可.jpg", userName:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可" ),
    Recipe(name: "蜂蜜法式吐司磚", type: "早餐", material: "1.吐司\n2.蛋\n3.牛奶\n4.蜂蜜\n5.糖粉", image: "toaste.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"2片\n1顆\n20CC\n依喜好\n依喜好", userPhoto:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可.jpg", userName:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可" ),
    Recipe(name: "蜂蜜法式吐司磚", type: "早餐", material: "1.吐司\n2.蛋\n3.牛奶\n4.蜂蜜\n5.糖粉", image: "toaste.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"2片\n1顆\n20CC\n依喜好\n依喜好", userPhoto:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可.jpg", userName:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可" ),
    Recipe(name: "蜂蜜法式吐司磚", type: "早餐", material: "1.吐司\n2.蛋\n3.牛奶\n4.蜂蜜\n5.糖粉", image: "toaste.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"2片\n1顆\n20CC\n依喜好\n依喜好", userPhoto:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可.jpg", userName:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可" ),
    Recipe(name: "蜂蜜法式吐司磚", type: "早餐", material: "1.吐司\n2.蛋\n3.牛奶\n4.蜂蜜\n5.糖粉", image: "toaste.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"2片\n1顆\n20CC\n依喜好\n依喜好", userPhoto:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可.jpg", userName:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可" ),
    Recipe(name: "蜂蜜法式吐司磚", type: "早餐", material: "1.吐司\n2.蛋\n3.牛奶\n4.蜂蜜\n5.糖粉", image: "toaste.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"2片\n1顆\n20CC\n依喜好\n依喜好", userPhoto:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可.jpg", userName:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可" ),
    Recipe(name: "蜂蜜法式吐司磚", type: "早餐", material: "1.吐司\n2.蛋\n3.牛奶\n4.蜂蜜\n5.糖粉", image: "toaste.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"2片\n1顆\n20CC\n依喜好\n依喜好", userPhoto:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可.jpg", userName:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可" ),
    Recipe(name: "蜂蜜法式吐司磚", type: "早餐", material: "1.吐司\n2.蛋\n3.牛奶\n4.蜂蜜\n5.糖粉", image: "toaste.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"2片\n1顆\n20CC\n依喜好\n依喜好", userPhoto:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可.jpg", userName:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可" ),
    Recipe(name: "蜂蜜法式吐司磚", type: "早餐", material: "1.吐司\n2.蛋\n3.牛奶\n4.蜂蜜\n5.糖粉", image: "toaste.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"2片\n1顆\n20CC\n依喜好\n依喜好", userPhoto:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可.jpg", userName:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可" ),
    Recipe(name: "蜂蜜法式吐司磚", type: "早餐", material: "1.吐司\n2.蛋\n3.牛奶\n4.蜂蜜\n5.糖粉", image: "toaste.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"2片\n1顆\n20CC\n依喜好\n依喜好", userPhoto:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可.jpg", userName:"Nico Sun 老孫妮可" ),

    ]

var noodles:[Recipe] = [
    Recipe(name: "辣味雞肉義大利麵", type: "麵食", material: "1.義大利麵\n2.雞胸肉\n3.洋蔥\n4.白酒\n5.蘆筍\n6.鴻喜菇\n7.玉米筍\n8.甜椒\n9.鮮奶油\n10.奶油\n11.蒜碎\n12.花椒油\n13.義大利香料", image: "pasta.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"180g\n50g\n15g\n50g\n15g\n10g\n10g\n5g\n150g\n10g\n5g\n20g\n2g", userPhoto:"Adrian Hsiao.jpg", userName:"Adrian Hsiao" ),
    Recipe(name: "焗烤海鮮筆管麵", type: "麵食", material: "1.筆管麵\n 2.洋蔥\n3.蛤蜊\n4.透抽\n5.鮮蝦\n6.蒜頭\n7.水\n8.康寶濃湯粉\n9.鹽\n10.起司絲\n11.煮熟綠花椰菜", image: "pasta2.jpg", isFavor: false, amount:"1/3包\n1顆\n適量\n適量\n適量\n三小瓣\n1杯半\n半包\n少許\n適量\n適量", userPhoto:"阿渝師～美味廚房.jpg", userName:"阿渝師～美味廚房" )
]

//var recipesIsDone = [Bool](count: 21, repeatedValue: false)

@IBAction func changePage(sender: AnyObject) {
    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
        self.category = 0
        print(category)
        //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showRecipesDetail", sender: self)
    }
    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
        self.category = 1
         print(category)
        //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showRecipesDetail", sender: self)
    }
    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
        self.category = 2
        //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showRecipesDetail", sender: self)
    }
    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 3 {
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
        self.category = 3
        //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showRecipesDetail", sender: self)
    }
    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 4 {
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
        self.category = 4
       // self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showRecipesDetail", sender: self)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //移除返回按鈕的標題
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "返回", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

    if revealViewController() != nil {
        //            revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 62
        menuButton.target = revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"

        revealViewController().rightViewRevealWidth = 150

        view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

//下兩個為建立tableView cell時必須建立的兩個function
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section
   // if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
    //}
    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        return self.recipes.count
    }
    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        return self.noodles.count
    }
    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        return self.noodles.count
    }
    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 3 {
        return self.noodles.count
    }
    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 4 {
        return self.noodles.count
    }
    return self.noodles.count

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    let recipe = recipes[indexPath.row]
    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        cell.favorIconImageView.hidden = !recipe.isFavor
        cell.nameLabel.text = recipe.name
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: recipe.image)
        // cell.locationLabel.text = recipe.material
        cell.typeLabel.text = recipe.type
        cell.userPhoto.image = UIImage(named: recipe.userPhoto)
        cell.userName.text = recipe.userName
    }

    let noodle = noodles[indexPath.row]
    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        cell.favorIconImageView.hidden = !noodle.isFavor
        cell.nameLabel.text = noodle.name
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: noodle.image)
        // cell.locationLabel.text = recipe.material
        cell.typeLabel.text = noodle.type
        cell.userPhoto.image = UIImage(named: noodle.userPhoto)
        cell.userName.text = noodle.userName
    }

    //let noodle = recipes[indexPath.row]
    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        cell.nameLabel.text = noodle.name
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: noodle.image)
        // cell.locationLabel.text = recipe.material
        cell.typeLabel.text = noodle.type
        cell.userPhoto.image = UIImage(named: noodle.userPhoto)
        cell.userName.text = noodle.userName
    }

    //let noodle = recipes[indexPath.row]
    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 3 {
        cell.nameLabel.text = noodle.name
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: noodle.image)
        // cell.locationLabel.text = recipe.material
        cell.typeLabel.text = noodle.type
        cell.userPhoto.image = UIImage(named: noodle.userPhoto)
        cell.userName.text = noodle.userName
    }

    //let noodle = recipes[indexPath.row]
    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 4 {
        cell.nameLabel.text = noodle.name
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: noodle.image)
        // cell.locationLabel.text = recipe.material
        cell.typeLabel.text = noodle.type
        cell.userPhoto.image = UIImage(named: noodle.userPhoto)
        cell.userName.text = noodle.userName
    }
    //I've been here
    //cell.accessoryType = recipesIsDone[indexPath.row] ? .Checkmark : .None
    //也可寫成
    /*
     if restaurantIsVisited[indexPath.rwo] {
     cell?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
     } else {
     cell?.accessoryType = .None
     }
     */


    //隱藏愛心圖片
    //cell.favorIconImageView.hidden = !recipe.isFavor


    /*
    //Circular image
    //cell.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    cell.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width / 2
    cell.thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    */


    return cell
}


//滑動刪除
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{
            self.recipes.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            //self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
        if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1{
            self.noodles.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            //self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
        if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2{
            self.noodles.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            //self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
        if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 3{
            self.noodles.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            //self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
        if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 4{
            self.noodles.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            //self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }



    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    var doneAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "收藏", handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        switch self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                let recipe = self.recipes[indexPath.row]
                recipe.isFavor = recipe.isFavor ? false : true
                cell.favorIconImageView.hidden = !recipe.isFavor
                print(recipe.isFavor)
            case 1:
                let noodle = self.noodles[indexPath.row]
                noodle.isFavor = noodle.isFavor ? false : true
                cell.favorIconImageView.hidden = !noodle.isFavor
                print(noodle.isFavor)

            default:
                /*let recipe = self.recipes[indexPath.row]
                recipe.isFavor = recipe.isFavor ? false : true
                cell.favorIconImageView.hidden = !recipe.isFavor
                print(recipe.isFavor)*/
                let noodle = self.noodles[indexPath.row]
                noodle.isFavor = noodle.isFavor ? false : true
                cell.favorIconImageView.hidden = !noodle.isFavor
                print(noodle.isFavor)
        }
        /*let recipe = self.recipes[indexPath.row]
        recipe.isFavor = recipe.isFavor ? false : true

        print(recipe.isFavor)*/

        //cell.accessoryType = self.recipesIsDone[indexPath.row] ? .Checkmark : .None


       }
    )

    var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete",handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

        //刪除列的資料
        switch self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            self.recipes.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

        case 1:
            self.noodles.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

        default:
            self.noodles.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }



    })

    //改變滑動按鈕的背景顏色
    doneAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 166.0/255.0, blue: 51.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    //deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 51.0/255.0, green: 51.0/255.0, blue: 51.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    //告訴表格滑動時要產生share跟delete的按鈕
    return [deleteAction, doneAction]
}

var category: Int = Int()
 //var : Int = Int()
//segue
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showRecipesDetail" {
       // var obj = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailTableViewCell
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

            if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                destinationController.recipes = recipes[indexPath.row]
                destinationController.category = self.category
                print(category)
            }
            if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
                destinationController.noodles = noodles[indexPath.row]
                destinationController.category = self.category
                 print(category)
            }
            if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
                destinationController.noodles = noodles[indexPath.row]
                destinationController.category = self.category
            }
            if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 3 {
                destinationController.noodles = noodles[indexPath.row]
                destinationController.category = self.category
            }
            if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 4 {
                destinationController.noodles = noodles[indexPath.row]
                destinationController.category = self.category
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't crashing here as well? `let noodle = noodles[indexPath.row]`? If you comment out this line `let recipe = recipes[indexPath.row]` does it work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume `segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0` and `indexPath.row == 2` (or any number, which >= `noodles.count`), and trace each line of your `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`:

```
//...

let recipe = recipes[indexPath.row]
if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
    cell.favorIconImageView.hidden = !recipe.isFavor
    cell.nameLabel.text = recipe.name
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: recipe.image)
    // cell.locationLabel.text = recipe.material
    cell.typeLabel.text = recipe.type
    cell.userPhoto.image = UIImage(named: recipe.userPhoto)
    cell.userName.text = recipe.userName
}

let noodle = noodles[indexPath.row] //<-control reaches here with `indexPath.row` == 2
//...
```

You may need to write something like this:

```
if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
    let recipe = recipes[indexPath.row]
    cell.favorIconImageView.hidden = !recipe.isFavor
    cell.nameLabel.text = recipe.name
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: recipe.image)
    // cell.locationLabel.text = recipe.material
    cell.typeLabel.text = recipe.type
    cell.userPhoto.image = UIImage(named: recipe.userPhoto)
    cell.userName.text = recipe.userName
} else {
    let noodle = noodles[indexPath.row]
    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        //...
    }

    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

Or:

```
if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
    let recipe = recipes[indexPath.row]
    cell.favorIconImageView.hidden = !recipe.isFavor
    cell.nameLabel.text = recipe.name
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: recipe.image)
    // cell.locationLabel.text = recipe.material
    cell.typeLabel.text = recipe.type
    cell.userPhoto.image = UIImage(named: recipe.userPhoto)
    cell.userName.text = recipe.userName
}

if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
    let noodle = noodles[indexPath.row]
    //...
}

if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
    let noodle = noodles[indexPath.row]
    //...
}

//...
```